# Open AI example code not working "Await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api

Apologies if this seems simple, I'm relatively new to this.

As said in the title I get the error "Await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules" Though I'm confused because the await is at the top of the body?

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: 'Api Key Go Brrrrrr',
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const response = await openai.createCompletion("text-davinci-002", {
  prompt: "You: What have you been up to?\nFriend: Watching old movies.\nYou: Did you watch anything interesting?\nFriend:",
  temperature: 0.5,
  max_tokens: 60,
  top_p: 1.0,
  frequency_penalty: 0.5,
  presence_penalty: 0.0,
  stop: ["You:"],
});
```

Comment: This is not a module program. Node.js supports experimental modules though.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the code in an async [`IIFE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
// add ; at the start to be safe, this is one of the very few cases where semicolons matter in JS
;(async ()=>{
const response = await openai.createCompletion("text-davinci-002", {
  prompt: "You: What have you been up to?\nFriend: Watching old movies.\nYou: Did you watch anything interesting?\nFriend:",
  temperature: 0.5,
  max_tokens: 60,
  top_p: 1.0,
  frequency_penalty: 0.5,
  presence_penalty: 0.0,
  stop: ["You:"],
});
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below:

```
 (async() => {
      const gptResponse = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: "text-davinci-003",
      prompt: "Say this is a test",
      temperature: 0,
      max_tokens: 7
      })

      console.log(gptResponse.data)
    })()
```

Answer (score -1):

if you can change your code to be in python, this may help: https://pypi.org/project/openai-async/

just do:

```
pip install openai-async
```

and then for example:

```
import openai_async

response = await openai_async.complete(
    "<API KEY>",
    timeout=2,
    payload={
        "model": "text-davinci-003",
        "prompt": "Correct this sentence: Me like you.",
        "temperature": 0.7,
    },
)
print(response.json()["choices"][0]["text"].strip()) # Output: "I like you."
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! As the question was clearly about javascript/nodejs, your answer may well be correct but possibly not helpful for the asker as he probably won't be able to port his application to python.

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap the completion code inside of an async function. Here is an example that works:

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: 'your api key',
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

async function main() {
    const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
        model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages: [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."}, {role: "user", content: "Hello world"}],
    });
    console.log(completion.data.choices[0].message);
}
main()
```

Comment: Code inside `main()` will never be executed.

Comment: It will if you type main() underneath it. This worked for me.